# JPA and Serialization behaviour

Tags: java, jpa, serialization, transient

Basically, i want to make a JPA-persisted field in my Entity behave like it is transient on manual serialization

i have a basic class like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foo implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
  long id;

  String field;

  get/set field;

}
```

On serialization the id is serialized too. When i Deserialize this class and persist it, it still has the same ID and is (after merging with JPA) the same instance in the database. While this is probably the intended behaviour, i want the deserialized object to be a new object in the database on deserialization.

I tried to make the id transient, but this messes up JPA. The second thing i tried was setting the id to null after deserialization. After that, persisting works. But This gets rather tedious with many different Entities and i get back to my original Question.

Is there an easier way than that? overriding the `readObject(...)` method and setting the id to null doesn't work either since JPA uses those methods too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend nulling out the id when you want a new object.  Making it transient seems like a bad idea, what if you need to serialize the real object at some point.

If you are using EclipseLink, it also offers a copy() API that can clone an object and null the id,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup#Copy_Examples

Answer (score 1):

Use property access by moving annotations to your getter methods, and mark the field as transient instead of using @Transient.  JPA will ignore the field and use the get/set methods to map the property, while serialization will see the field is transient and ignore it:

```
@Entity
public class Foo implements Serializable{
  transient long id;
  String field;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
  public long getId(){ return id; }
  ..

  @Basic
  public String getField() {return field;}
  ..
```

Comment: That would be nice, but it says `Entity class [...] has no primary key defined`

Comment: Then you didn't set the access type and still annotations on fields.  You cannot mix annotations on properties and fields or some are ignored, unless you use the Access annotation in JPA 2 to define it and override it for some mappings.  Simpler to keep them consistent on your properties though